# Why does my production logs show an ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique error but my local binding.pry shows me an ActiveModel::Errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec, activemodel

I have a signup form that contains validations on the model and database to prevent duplicate entries.

I use honeybadger in production for my error logging. When a user attempts to sign up with the same credentials, honeybadger reports a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry for ....`. The rest of the error contains PII, which I'm trying to prevent (I work for a financial firm so this is a compliance issue).

My solution was to wrap the `Model.create` in a rescue block and customize the honeybadger error before its report. I wrote some rspecs for it, which kept failing. When I included a binding.pry within the block, I can see the duplicate create an error, but the error is an instance of `ActiveModel::Errors`. Now, I can try to rescue the `ActiveModel::Errors` error but then I'm afraid that the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` error would still be logged on production, which is what I'm working to change.

I can't figure out:

1) Why production and local would show different types of errors?

2) Which class of error I would have to rescue from in order to provide the custom error message (and hide the PII) from our production logging.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Some things I've tried as an overall solution are:

1) Use prepared statements. This didn't work however because the version of ActiveRecord (4.2.11) I'm using doesn't have prepared statements.

2) Use Honeybadger's ability to ignore errors following this: 
https://docs.honeybadger.io/lib/ruby/getting-started/ignoring-errors.html, but, the team decided we don't want to turn off the error completely.

```rb
# /app/models/prime_signup.rb
class PrimeSignup < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :email
 validates :email, uniqueness: true

  def person
    @person ||= Person.find_by(email: email)
  end

  def full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

```rb
# /db/schema.rb
create_table "prime_signups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name",   limit: 255
    t.string   "last_name",    limit: 255
    t.string   "email",        limit: 255
    t.string   "phone_number", limit: 20
  end

  add_index "prime_signups", ["email"], name: "index_prime_signups_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
```

```rb
# /app/controllers/api/v1/prime_signups_controller.rb

class API::V1::PrimeSignupsController < API::V1Controller
 // omitting skip_before_actions for brevity

  def create
    return render_forward_compatible_json_error(json_error, resource) unless resource.valid?
    service.perform
    render json: resource, serializer: API::V1::PrimeSignupSerializer, status: 201
  end

  private

  def resource_params
    params.require(:prime_signup).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone_number,
                                         :utm_source, :utm_medium, :utm_campaign, :utm_term,
                                         :utm_content)
  end

  def resource # This is the method I'm trying to rescue the error from
    binding.pry 
    begin
      @resource ||= PrimeSignup.create(resource_params)
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique => e  # This is how I'm trying to customize the error
      Honeybadger.notify(
        error,
        error_message: 'Duplicate Entry',
      )
    end
  end

  def json_error
    JSONExceptions::InvalidFieldValues.new(detail: resource_errors)
  end

  def resource_errors
    resource.errors.messages.map {|field, message| "#{field} #{message.join}."}.join(" ")
  end

  def service
    ::Services::PrimeSignupCreation.new(resource)
  end

  def render_forward_compatible_json_error(error, resource)
    json_error_format = { errors: [error.to_json] }
    resource_key = resource.class.name.snakecase
    old_error_format = {resource_key => resource.errors.details}
    render json: json_error_format.merge(old_error_format), status: error.status
  end
end
```

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'API::V1::PrimeSignups', type: :request do
  describe 'POST /api/v1/prime_signups' do
    context 'duplicate entry' do
      it 'raises a custom honeybadger error' do

        prime_signup_params = {
          prime_signup: {
            first_name: "Walter",
            last_name: "White",
            email: "walter@white.com",
            phone_number: '123456789'
          },
          authenticity_token: 'authenticated',
          format: :json
        }

        expect(Honeybadger).to receive(:notify)
        VCR.use_cassette('/api/v1/prime_signups') do
          post '/api/v1/prime_signups', prime_signup_params.to_json, { "CONTENT_TYPE"=>"application/json" }
          post '/api/v1/prime_signups', prime_signup_params.to_json, { "CONTENT_TYPE"=>"application/json" }
        end
        expect(response.status).to eq(422)

        # VCR.use_cassette('/api/v1/prime_signups') do
        #   post '/api/v1/prime_signups', prime_signup_params.to_json, { "CONTENT_TYPE"=>"application/json" }
        # end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I expect the error rescued from to be of the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` type or the production error logged to be of the `ActiveModel::Errors` type. Basically expecting consistency between the two.

Also, any guidance on the specs and better formatting it would be greatly appreciated. I'm terrible at it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are seeing `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` in production but `ActiveModel::Errors` locally is probably due to a race condition in production that you aren't replicating locally.

That is, in production what is likely happening is that the uniqueness validation is passing because two records with duplicate info are trying to be created at the same time, and each in-flight record is valid because they both find no existing records in the database with the same email address. One of the creations succeeds, and then the second fails because the first one got persisted by the database after the second one did its uniqueness query but before it could do its insert.

In your test environment, the two attempted creations are happening sequentially, rather than simultaneously, so the second attempt doesn't get past the uniqueness check.

To test the controller's production behavior, you would need to stub `PrimeSignup.create` and have it raise the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` error.

Though you didn't ask this, I'll also give you a suggestion on an alternate approach, since I happen to be one of the Honeybadger co-founders... :) You can add the `email` parameter to the [list of filtered parameters](https://docs.honeybadger.io/lib/ruby/getting-started/filtering-sensitive-data.html) in your Honeybadger configuration, and then that PII wouldn't get reported along with the rest of the error information.

Comment: Hey Benjamin. Thanks for your reply and the awesome company you and your team have created. We love your product. The race condition makes total sense. For your last part, in our configuration, we've disabled all params. So it sounds like the ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique message may be outside of that configuration for some reason (possibly a mysql string is being reported?)

Comment: Oh, right... I'm sorry -- I was thinking of filtering params, but you need to filter the query from the error message that is associated with the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` error.

Here's how we handle that in our Rails app: https://gist.github.com/stympy/39aa691f90b97fb4e4912ecbeb8ddbe0

In our case, we're removing private key data from a Postgres query, so you'll need to tweak that a bit, but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

This way Rails validation should not allow the save if it fails validations and you don't have to deal with rescue exception at all.

```
def resource 
  @resource ||= PrimeSignup.find_or_initialize_by(resource_params)
    if @resource.save
      Honeybadger.notify(
        @resource.errors.full_messages,
        error_message:  @resource.errors.full_messages.join(', ')
      )
    end
  end
end
```